# Flling Dictionary with class from console until "End" is pressed

Tags: c#

I have picked up programming for a month now and stumbled across this problem. 
My task is to fill a Dictionary full of bank accounts until i type "End" from this method. Also if i have bank account with same id in the Dictionary i have to display a message that says"Account doesnt work":

```
private static void Create(string[] cmdArgs, Dictionary<int, BankAccount> accounts)
        {
            var id = int.Parse(cmdArgs[1]);
            if(accounts.ContainsKey(id))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Account already exists");`
            }
            else
            {
                var account = new BankAccount();
                account.ID = id;
                accounts.Add(id,account);
            }
        }
```

Here is my BankAccount class code:

```
class BankAccount
    { 
        private int id;
        private double balance;

        public void Deposit(double amount)
        {
                this.balance += amount;
        }

        public void Withdraw(double amount)
        {
                this.balance -= amount;
        }

        public double Balance
        {
            get { return balance; }
            set { balance = value; }
        }

        public int ID
        {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
                return $"Account {ID} has {Balance}";
        }
    }
```

And here is the Main that is given:

```
Dictionary<int, BankAccount> accounts = new Dictionary<int, BankAccount>();
            var cmdArgs=command.Split();
            var cmdType=cmdArgs[0];
            switch (cmdType)
                {
                    case "Create":
                        {
                            //Todo
                            Create(cmdArgs,accounts)
                        }
                }
```

And this is my Main that doesnt work:

```
while (command[0] != "End")
            {
                switch (command[0])
                {
                    case "Create":
                        {
                            int id = int.Parse(command[1]);
                            if (accounts.ContainsKey(id))
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("Account already exists");
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                var account = new BankAccount();
                                account.ID = id;
                                accounts.Add(id, account);
                            }
                            break;
                        }
                }
```

The error is that it spams Account already exists. I guess it is because i have made an "open" loop but i dont get it since i have break.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what is not working? Are you getting errors? Inconsistent results? Something else?

Comment: Hi @Deqn. You need to actually ask a question? What **exactly** are you wanting from us here?

Comment: You dont seem to be checking for "End" at any point or looping until you have one

Comment: You should use the `Console.ReadLine()` to get some input from the user. It looks like your example is not complete. Are you forgetting to post a working example?

Comment: I am reading from the console but i have made an open loop not knowing how

Comment: Once you enter the `while` loop, when does `command[0]` ever change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question still is not clear. However, consider the following version of your codes. Is that what you need?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var accounts = new Dictionary<int, BankAccount>();

        string[] command;

        do
        {
            command = Console.ReadLine().Split();

            if (command[0] == "Create")
                Create(command, accounts);

        } while (command[0] != "End");

        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void Create(string[] cmdArgs, Dictionary<int, BankAccount> accounts)
    {
        var id = int.Parse(cmdArgs[1]);
        if (accounts.ContainsKey(id))
            Console.WriteLine("Account already exists");
        else
            accounts.Add(id, new BankAccount { ID = id });
    }
}

class BankAccount
{
    public double Balance { get; set; }
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() => $"Account {ID} has {Balance}";
    public void Deposit(double amount) => Balance += amount;
    public void Withdraw(double amount) => Balance -= amount;
}
```